# UITableView background now scrolling with cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've noticed something:
I've an UITableViewController with a custom background, set this way:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
```

On iPhone Simulator 4.1, the background shows correctly, fixed and never moving...
But when I use iPhone Simulator 4.2 or 4.3, the background is scrolling with the cells !
I suppose this is a change made by Apple on iOS 4.2, but how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the backgroundView of the tableView to a UIImageView results in an image that remains in a fixed position.

```
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;
[backgroundImageView release];
```

Comment: When i set the custom view on the background it scroll